# When does type checking of generic definitions and instantiations happen in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, programming-languages, computer-science

In C#,

- does type checking of generic definitions happen at compile time?
- does type checking of instantiations of generics happen at run time?

Thanks.

The above questions are for me to understand the quotes in bold from C# in a Nutshell:

> However, with C# generics, **producer types (i.e., open types such as 
>   List ) can be compiled  into  a  library  (such  as  mscorlib.dll)**.
>   This  works  because  **the  synthesis between the producer and the
>   consumer that produces closed types doesn’t actually happen until
>   runtime.**
>
> To dig deeper into why this is the case, consider the  Max  method in
>   C#, once more:
>
> ```
> static T Max <T> (T a, T b) where T : IComparable<T>
>   => a.CompareTo (b) > 0 ? a : b;
> ```
>
> Why couldn’t we have implemented it like this?
>
> ```
> static T Max <T> (T a, T b)
>   => (a > b ? a : b);             // Compile error
> ```
>
> The reason is that  `Max`  needs to be compiled once and work for all
>   possible values of `T` . Compilation cannot succeed, because there is
>   no single meaning for  `>`  across all values of  `T` —in fact, not
>   every  `T`  even has a  `>`  operator.

I also have [the same question for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46288594/156458).

Answer (score 1):

Both generic definitions and instantiations are checked at compile time. Further, they can be checked separately. Unlike C++ where you may have an error in your template that you don't discover until you later try to instantiate it, in C#, any compile errors in a generic declaration will be found when the declaration itself is compiled.

The magic that enables this that C++ lacks is [constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters). This is what the example is showing you.

When you define a generic method or class, you can put constraints on the type parameters. Those limit which instantiations are allowed but also determine what operations you can take advantage of in the body of the generic declaration.

When the declaration is compiled, the compiler checks that you don't do anything with a type parameter that its constraints don't allow. So, for example, you'd get an error here:

```
T Foo<T> (T a) => a.CompareTo(b);
```

You're trying to call `CompareTo` on `a`, whose type is `T`. The compiler has no way of knowing that a user will only instantiate Foo with types that do have that method, so it pessimistically assumes it could be instantiated with a type that doesn't have that and prevents you from compiling this declaration.

When you change it to:

```
T Foo<T> (T a) where T : IComparable => a.CompareTo(b);
```

Now it knows every instantiation of T *must* have a `CompareTo()` method, so it compiles this.

Later when someone tries to instantiate Foo with some type, if the type does not implement IComparable, they get a compile error. Since the method says "You can only use me with types that implement IComparable", the compiler ensures they meet that constraint.

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of type-checking is to detect errors at compile-time i.e. before the software is used. This prevents bugs from reaching the users.

C# generic types are checked at compile-time. See the [Benefits of Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/benefits-of-generics).

C# also does type-checking at run-time in certain situations, but that is too late to prevent bugs - the application is already running and being used.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the compiler checks the usage of generic argument at compile time and generate “generic aware type”. There rea especial instructions in IL for this kind of operation. C# compiler uses any restriction at the generic definition to allow operation on generic argument. So, answer on the first question – Yes, it does check generic argument type. During definition of regular type based on generic type compiler checks if the type satisfies all restrictions and if so generate another type, internal one, for using with the combination of generic type and arguments. The compiler will use that generated type for all other instances of combination generic type and its argument type, but this, second phase, happened at runtime when request for creating of particular generic type with argument.
When type is created it is just regular, not generic type event the base class of it is generic and compiler uses common approach to check types related to any instance of this type.